# How to adapt Vue component for browser build?

Tags: vue.js

I have a legacy web application which I have introduced Vue into in a few places, via CDN. I have upgraded it from Vue 2 to Vue 3. There is a component used there which breaks with Vue 3, but there is a Vue 3 version of it. However, the author states this: "The component is packaged mainly for use with bundlers, if you require a browser build - post an issue." I do require a browser build. Is there some easy way I can do this for myself? I wasn't planning to use a bundler for this application, so I'm hoping I can use the existing modules to create a .js file I can use from the browser?